Is checking GCD in NC or strongly P?
Given two integers $m$ and $n$ computing $\mathsf{GCD}(m,n)$ is not known to be either in $NC$ or in strongly Polynomial time.

Given three integers $m$, $n$ and $g$, is testing $g=\mathsf{GCD}(m,n)$ or not in either $NC$ or in strongly Polynomial time?


The special case $g=1$ is coprimality testing, which is not known to be posible in NC, as you are well aware. In fact, testing $g=\gcd(m,n)$ is equivalent to coprimality testing, as $g=\gcd(m,n)\iff g\mid m\land g\mid n\land\gcd(m/g,n/g)=1$.

It is highly unclear to me what you mean by “strongly polynomial time”. The standard definition says that the problem can be computed by arithmetic circuits of size polynomial in the number of numerical inputs such that the intermediate results of the computation of the circuits have bit-size in the bit-size of the inputs. This is meant for algorithms that take a long sequence of numbers as an input, and it does not seem to make much sense here. If you mean that the sequence of inputs is the sequence of ${0,1}$ bits of $g,n,m$, then the problem trivially is strongly polynomial time: ...

... just take polynomial-size Boolean circuits implementing the usual polynomial-time algorithm for the problem, and simulate Boolean gates by arithmetic gates ($\neg x=1-x$, $x\land y=xy$). The intermediate results are all ${0,1}$, hence this is strongly polynomial time. If, on the other hand, you mean that the input numbers are $g,n,m$ themselves, then the problem trivially is not strongly polynomial time, even in simple special cases like testing parity ($1=\gcd(2,n)$): the definition would require that the problem is computable by a constant-size arithmetic circuit, i.e., it is ...

... expressible as a fixed Boolean combination of polynomial equalities (and inequalities, depending on the exact arithmetic circuit model). This is impossible as no univariate polynomial can change sign infinitely many times.

"...on the other hand, you mean that the input numbers are g,n,m
themselves, then the problem trivially is not strongly polynomial time..." that is what I mean.
